# How to create a custom Ordering?

Tags: rust, heap

I want to form the following data structure using the standard library binary heap: use std::collections::BinaryHeap;

```
let mut heap: BinaryHeap<BinaryHeap<(i32, usize, usize)>> = BinaryHeap::new();
```

And the order of the overarching BinaryHeap depends on the highest value of the peek in the containing binary heaps. For example, if I have two heaps within the overarching binary heap like:

heap1: (3, 0, 5), (2, 0, 6)
heap2: (5, 2, 6), (3, 3, 9)

Then I want heap2 to be the max item in the overarching heap since its peek value, i.e, (5, 2, 6) is greater than heap1's peek value, (3, 0, 5). I tried the following:

```
use std::collections::BinaryHeap;
use core::cmp::Ordering;
#[derive(Eq)]
struct MyBinaryHeap<T>(BinaryHeap<T>);
impl Ord for MyBinaryHeap<(i32, usize, usize)> {
    fn cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Ordering {
        &self.peek().cmp(&other.peek());
    }
}

impl PartialOrd for MyBinaryHeap<(i32, usize, usize)> {
    fn partial_cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Option<Ordering> {
        Some(self.cmp(other))
    }
}

impl PartialEq for MyBinaryHeap<(i32, usize, usize)> {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        self.peek().0 == other.peek().0
    }
}
```

But this gives me the error:

```
Line 3, Char 10: can't compare `MyBinaryHeap<T>` with `MyBinaryHeap<T>` (solution.rs)
    |
3   | #[derive(Eq)]
    |          ^^ no implementation for `MyBinaryHeap<T> == MyBinaryHeap<T>`
    |
    = help: the trait `std::cmp::PartialEq` is not implemented for `MyBinaryHeap<T>`
    = note: this error originates in a derive macro (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
error: aborting due to previous error
```

How to implement Ord correctly? Additionally, I also want this overarching heap to work when an element is popped within one of the internal heaps. Therefore, the heap should be able to self-adjust itself if an element within is changed. However, the self-adjusting property is not a hard requirement and I can live without it.

Answer (score 2):

1. > How to implement Ord correctly?

   As documented under [How can I implement `Ord`?](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.Ord.html#how-can-i-implement-ord)

   > `Ord` requires that the type also be [`PartialOrd`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.PartialOrd.html) and [`Eq`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.Eq.html) (which requires [`PartialEq`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.PartialEq.html)).

   Therefore ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=451463e9cec5e7b91419f2b587b8e66d)):

   ```
   use std::collections::BinaryHeap;
   use core::cmp::Ordering;

   struct MyBinaryHeap<T>(BinaryHeap<T>);

   impl Ord for MyBinaryHeap<(i32, usize, usize)> {
       fn cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Ordering {
           self.0.peek().cmp(&other.0.peek())
       }
   }

   impl PartialOrd for MyBinaryHeap<(i32, usize, usize)> {
       fn partial_cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Option<Ordering> {
           Some(self.cmp(other))
       }
   }

   impl PartialEq for MyBinaryHeap<(i32, usize, usize)> {
       fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
           self.cmp(other) == Ordering::Equal
       }
   }

   impl Eq for MyBinaryHeap<(i32, usize, usize)> {}
   ```

   But actually, you could be more generic and apply this to any `T` ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c4bffa86b672ae71c7b7f20d7d8b5130)):

   ```
   use std::collections::BinaryHeap;
   use core::cmp::Ordering;

   struct MyBinaryHeap<T>(BinaryHeap<T>);

   impl<T: Ord> Ord for MyBinaryHeap<T> {
       fn cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Ordering {
           self.0.peek().cmp(&other.0.peek())
       }
   }

   impl<T: PartialOrd> PartialOrd for MyBinaryHeap<T> {
       fn partial_cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Option<Ordering> {
           self.0.peek().partial_cmp(&other.0.peek())
       }
   }

   impl<T: PartialEq> PartialEq for MyBinaryHeap<T> {
       fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
           self.0.peek() == other.0.peek()
       }
   }

   impl<T: Eq> Eq for MyBinaryHeap<T> {}
   ```
2. > I also want this overarching heap to work when an element is popped within one of the internal heaps. Therefore, the heap should be able to self-adjust itself if an element within is changed.

   If the internal heaps are only ever modified through the outer heap's `peek_mut()` method, then this is guaranteed.

Comment: Why do you have a 0 at self and at other like 0.peek()?

Comment: @lampbottle: to access the `BinaryHeap` contained within `MyBinaryHeap`.

Comment: How are you able to == with Ordering::Equal while defining the meaning of eq?

Comment: @lampbottle: it's comparing the result of `Ord::cmp` to the enum variant `Ordering::Equal`.

Comment: Also to access the BinaryHeap contained within the BinaryHeap, why do you need to index to 0. Shouldn't it just be self.peek() and other.peek()?

Comment: This isn't working: let mut heap: MyBinaryHeap<MyBinaryHeap<(i32, usize, usize)>> = MyBinaryHeap::new();
function or associated item new not found for this

Comment: @lampbottle: `MyBinaryHeap` is not transparent.  It is a full-on, proper, normal struct like any other you might create.  It has its own methods.  You may want to implement `Deref` and `DerefMut` so that calls that only require a reference to the inner heap get automatically forwarded on .  You'll still need to define associated functions like `new` yourself, however: `impl MyBinaryHeap { fn new() -> Self { MyBinaryHeap(BinaryHeap::new()) } }`.

Comment: Can you tell me how would push and pop will be implemented without having to ask a separate question?

Comment: @lampbottle: I suggest you implement `Deref` and `DerefMut`.  See [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3fbd5182b1c93f810ec280bf8bfd7ba3).